# JPA entities: inheritance and one-to-one relationship not working simultaneously

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb

I have the following scheme: TableA1 and TableA2 exist in the database and each is represented by an entity bean. Since they are related, I created an abstract class (TableA, it's an entity but does not exist in the database) where both entities inherit from this class. In addition, TableA has a one-to-one relationship with TableB.

My objective is to query TableB and from there get information of TableA1 or TableA2 depending on the type.

TableA1 and TableA2 each has an id (each table generates automatically a sequential number, so you may have repetition).

In TableB I have two columns that combined represent the foreign key: type and id. Type = 1 means that id is in TableA1. Similarly with TableA2.

My problem is that I don't know how to define these two columns as an external foreign key.
This is what I've got:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
public abstract class TableA { 

    @Id
    @Column(name = "type")
    protected int type;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    // Getters and setters

}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
@Table (name="tableA1")
public class TableA1 extends TableA {

    @Column(name="col1")
    private String col1;

    // Getters and setters

}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
@Table (name="tableA2")
public class TableA2 extends TableA {

    @Column(name="col2")
    private String col2;

    // Getters and setters
}


@Entity
@Table (name="tableB")
public class TableB {

    @Id 
    @Column(name="someId")
    private Integer someId;


    @Column(name="type")
    private int type;

    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;   


    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({    
        @JoinColumn(name = "type"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "id" )
      })
    private TableA tableA;

    // Getters and setters

}
```

**Update**

Am I looking for the impossible? This is what I found:

> Polymorphic relations to non-leaf classes in a table-per-class hierarchy have many limitations. When the concrete subclass is not known, the related object could be in any of the subclass tables, making joins through the relation impossible. This ambiguity also affects identity lookups and queries; these operations require multiple SQL SELECTs (one for each possible subclass), or a complex UNION.

**Update 2**

TableA1, TableA2 and TableB **already exist** in the database and have the following structure:

```
 CREATE TABLE TableA1 (
   surrogate_key int AUTO_INCREMENT,
   some_char char(30),
   PRIMARY KEY (surrogate_key)
 );

CREATE TABLE TableA2 (
   surrogate_key int AUTO_INCREMENT,
   some_int int,
   PRIMARY KEY (surrogate_key)
);

CREATE TABLE TableB (
   surrogate_key int AUTO_INCREMENT,
   type int,  // if type=1, sk represents the surrogate_key of tableA1
              // if type=2, sk represents the surrogate_key of tableA2
   sk int,
   description varchar(200),
   PRIMARY KEY (surrogate_key)
 );
```

Comment: Maybe add an EER diagram so we can understand this complex hibernate question.

Comment: yes, if type=1 then sk points to TableA1, if type=2 then sk points to TableA2, if type = 0 then sk = 0. That is why I'm trying to use `@DiscriminatorValue`

Comment: I've only seen Discriminator used for single table inheritance. Aren't your tables `TableA1` & `TableA2` missing the type columns? Or does Hibernate just use them internally?

Comment: If I add the type column to TableA1 and TableA2 then these columns would have constant values ('1' and '2' respectively). I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: What are your constraints? Is the table structure frozen or are the JPA entities code frozen? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The database structure cannot be changed, the JPA entities can be anything. This is what I'm trying to achieve: TableB is related to either TableA1 or TableA2, depending on the type column. If type=1 then sk represents the surrogate key of TableA1. Similarly with type=2. If type=0, then there's no relationship. When I load a row from TableB I need to also retrieve a row from the related TableA1 or TableA2.

Comment: By the way, this model works if I use `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` and have a single table for both TableA1 and TableA2 (the type would be declared in `@DiscriminatorValue`). I want to avoid having a single table.

Answer (score 1):

**Update answer:**

**Updated to match database**

You can use getDiscriminatorValue() to access the DiscriminatorValue.

Define mappings like this:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class TableA implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
  @Column(name = "surrogate_key")
  protected int id;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "type")
  protected int type;

  // Constructors & getters/setters

  @Transient
  public String getDiscriminatorValue() {
    DiscriminatorValue val = this.getClass().getAnnotation(DiscriminatorValue.class);
    return val == null ? null : val.value();      
  }
}        


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class TableA1 extends TableA {

  @Column(name = "some_char", length = 1)
  private char someChar;

  // Constructors & getters/setters & toString/equals
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class TableA2 extends TableA {

  @Column(name = "some_int")
  private int someInt;

  // Constructors & getters/setters & toString/equals
}

@Entity
public class TableB implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "surrogate_key")
  private int id;

  @OneToOne
  @Cascade(value = CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
  @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "sk", referencedColumnName = "surrogate_key"),
  @JoinColumn(name = "type", referencedColumnName = "type")})
  private TableA tableA;

  @Column(name = "description", length = 200)
  private String description;

  // Constructors & getters/setters & toString/equals

}
```

and query like this:

```
newSession.createQuery("from TableB tb where tb.tableA.type=:type order by tb.id asc").setParameter("type", 1));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to avoid using `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE` as TableA1 and TableA2 already exist in the database and I wouldn't like to consolidate them in a single table as their structure differ a lot. Please take a look at **Update 2**.

Comment: what's the objective of `hibernate_sequences` ? I'm trying to avoid adding a type column to TableA1 and TableA2 as these columns would contain a constant value.

Comment: It's used for generating the primary keys(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE) I need to use this strategy, gives me errors otherwise. Don't pay attention to much to it. I'm using HSQLDB & Hibernate tools to generate the tables.